# How to update client side angular5 array using array.filter?

Tags: typescript, angular5, array-filter

I am implementing array filtering in Angular5.

Here is my component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
 this.getFileDetails();
 this.recordsCopy = this.records;
}

getFileDetails() {
this.appService.fetchFileDetails(this.filename).then((resp: any) => {
  if (resp.success) {
    this.records = resp.data;
    this.records.map(item=>{
      item.editable = false;
     })
   }
  });
 }

  nameSearchFilter(event : any){
    const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    console.log(val);
    this.recordsCopy  = this.records.filter(function (d) {
     return d.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
  });
 }
```

Here is my component.html

```
<div class="tale-responsive">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Speciality</th>
              <th>Credentials</th>
              <th>City</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control"  (keyup)='nameSearchFilter($event)'/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="table-responsive">
<div class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Speciality</th>
    <th>Credentials</th>
    <th>City</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let record of records">
    <td>{{record.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{record.Specailty}}</td>
    <td>{{record.Credentials}}</td>
    <td>{{record.City}}</td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

I am implementing array filtering on `keyup` angular event so that as user starts type then array should display table filtration real time.
But it is not working. Where i am mistaking in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are permanently modifying your data source.

The easiest non-angular way of doing this would be to create a `filteredRecords` copy that you *only assign*, while still filtering your original `records`.

```
this.filteredRecords = this.records.filter(...)
```

If you wanted to be more angulary, you could make a filter pipe that does this for you on the way to your template.

Comment: so exactly where should i change in my code and what?

Comment: but i have my all array data orignially in `records` array which i bind in my html so at the time of page load it displays all data into html if i replace `records` with `filteredRecords` so there will be no records at page load

Comment: I have also tried this

`nameSearchFilter(event : any){
    this.recordsCopy = this.records;
    const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    console.log(val);
    this.recordsCopy = this.recordsCopy.filter(function (d) {
      return d.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
    });
    this.records = this.recordsCopy;
  }`
But is not working

Comment: Thanx. I got it.

Comment: i just posted question with static declared array with records to just correct my filter logic. I applied your logic onto stackblitz code that have static array with records so it is working. But when i used your logic in my actual project which fetches records on Angular  `ngOnInit` so it stops working. I have updated the post. Please respond it accordingly

Comment: Sorry i was mistaking in code. Your example worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying your source `records` array in `nameSearchFilter` method. That's wrong. You need to create a `recordsToDisplay` array and use it to draw table rows and assign the results of filtering into it.

Comment: I have also tried this

`nameSearchFilter(event : any){
    this.recordsCopy = this.records;
    const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    console.log(val);
    this.recordsCopy = this.recordsCopy.filter(function (d) {
      return d.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
    });
    this.records = this.recordsCopy;
  }`
But is not working